# Loading an array on a sub view with data from main view

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, xcode4

My application has two views. Main view allows to enter details of a product and stores to an array in the second view. Whenever I switches to second view, all product details should be loaded to a table view.

The problem is that whenever I try to add a product to the array, it saves data but replaces previous data. So all the time array is stored with only one product info. I assume the array is getting initialised every time when I add a product. Here is the code,

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        productArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I tried to allocate array in viewDidLoad method and many other places but nothing helped.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if I understand your question, but:

1. If you want to add an object to an array, you should set the array as `NSMutableArray` and call the `addObject` method on it so that the array will now contain your new object.
2. If you want to pass the array from your main view to your second view, you should do it in your segue setup. Basically you have a `@property` in your second view, and in the `performSegue` method in your main view, you set the `@property` to whatever array you wish it to be.

You cannot use segue without storyboard (at least i don't know how). So if you want to use xib, you need to do it in the traditional way:

```
SomeViewController *viewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nib" bundle:nil];;
viewController.array = self.array;  // the array you want to pass to your new view
```

So in your alloc-init thing, you only instantiated your array, but you didn't seem to pass the data to it?

Comment: @iBlue.. Thanks for the quick reply. I am using NSMutable array with addObject method. Could you please provide a sample code which uses Segue. By the way I am not using Storyboard. It is a single view application with additional ViewController and xib file.